# How to replace or delete lines containing / character in BASH?

Tags: sed, binary, character

I have a file that starts with some text lines and continues with many binary lines. I need to delete text line from its beginning to gain a pure binary content. Assume that binary section begins with a special word like: Connection. I tried to do this using a bash script with `sed` to delete all those text lines. The problem is: text lines containing `/` character cause `sed` to interpret character after `/` in input as a separate command. My code is like this:

```
while read line
  do
        sed -i "/"$line"/d" file_name

        if [ "$line" != Connection* ]
                break;

  done < file_name
```

this way, when variable "line" contains `/` character (for example css/jj) sed returns an error :

> sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `j'

How can I pass variables containing `/` character to the `sed` to delete related lines?
By the way, is there a way to separate binary content from text in a file? Sometimes my files don't have any special word or sign at beginning of binary section to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely replace `/` delimiter by any other character, provided that you replace it in every occurrence, Sometimes, I use `§` which is quite uncommon in most texts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I read in sed tutorials using other delimiters is possible just for replacement (with flag s) and is not possible for deletion. fortunately I could solve my problem of extracting binary content from files (actually tcp stream files obtained from tcpflow) by means of "foremost" tool and then customising its configuration.

Comment: You are both right and wrong. An address in the form `/.../` may be changed to `\c...c` where `c` is any character. When using the command `s/.../.../` the delimiters may be changed like so `sc...c...c` where `c` is any character.